# Creating Kendall's Tau function and does not work

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function that calculates Kendall's tau coefficient using r.

So far, I've got

```
tau <- function(x,y) {

  nc = 0
  nd = 0
  for(i in 1:(n-1))
  {
    for(j in (i+1):n)
    {
      
      if (x[i]<x[j] & y[i]<y[j])

        nc = nc+1

      else if (x[i]>x[j] & y[i]>y[j])

        nc = nc+1

      else

        nd = nd+1

      return(nc-nd/(n*(n-1)/2))
    }
  }
}
```

The function looks ok but When I run the function,

For example,

```
 tau(4,6)
Error in n - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I get this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: `n` is not defined.

Comment: solved thank you!!